# Error with implementing sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to link sqlite3, create table and insert data but got this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error creating table: near "4": syntax error' *** First throw call stack:(0x15ad022 0x173ecd6 0x1555a48 0xa852cb 0x2bea 0x273a 0x1b5a1e 0x114401 0x114670 0x114836 0x11b72a 0x2415 0xec386 0xed274 0xfc183 0xfcc38 0xf0634 0x1497ef5 0x1581195 0x14e5ff2 0x14e48da 0x14e3d84 0x14e3c9b 0xecc65 0xee626 0x20d2 0x2045 0x1)
```

the code:

```
- (void) openDBcreateTable {
if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}
//create table named QUESTIONBANK
NSString *createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QUESTIONBANK(ROW INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, QUESTION TEXT, ANSWER TEXT, CHOICE1 TEXT, CHOICE2 TEXT, CHOICE3 TEXT, CHOICE 4 TEXT, USERANSWER TEXT);";

char *errorMsg1;

if (sqlite3_exec(db, [createSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg1) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0,@"Error creating table: %s", errorMsg1);
}

for (int k = 1; k < 11; k++) {
    NSMutableArray *questionBlocks = [self pullDataFromSomeWhere];
    NSString *question = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSString *choice1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSString *choice2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:3]];
    NSString *choice3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:4]];
    NSString *choice4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[questionBlocks objectAtIndex:5]];

    char *update = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO QUESTIONBANK(ROW,QUESTION,ANSWER,CHOICE1,CHOICE2,CHOICE3,CHOICE4)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";


    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, update, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, k);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [question UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [answer UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [choice1 UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [choice2 UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [choice3 UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, [choice4 UTF8String], -1, NULL);

    }
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert(0,@"Error updating table");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(db);}
```

I'm also very confident that there are other errors since i'm still new to sqlite 3. While we're at this, is there any 'VARCHAR', 'BLOB' etc (like MySQL) that i can use in sqlite3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spurious '4' in the create table statement:

`... CHOICE 4 TEXT ...`

should be:

`... CHOICE TEXT ...`

The error message is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: What a bummer... LoL... Need to get some sleep.. The rest seems alright? Please do criticize the approach i took if any... Thanx again...

Comment: @TeamStar The rest looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your data types question, I think the [SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) addresses this clearly. Bottom line, SQLite has limited data types, and it doesn't enforce the types of your data columns (so you can store any of the data types in any column). No explicit VARCHAR data type.